# java process builder .sh terminal disappears

Tags: java, bash, terminal, processbuilder

I have a process builder which runs a .sh script. 
The terminal just appears for a second and then disappears again and the java program terminates. Knowing that running this script from terminal runs a server and keeps it running.

Code:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", "-e", "/home/omar/ros_ws/baxter2.sh").start();
```

Comment: Can you run `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e /home/omar/ros_ws/baxter2.sh` on the command line?

Comment: The same as described. Appeared and disappeared again.

Comment: Does the script output something if you run it in a terminal without spawning the new terminal window? ie. just run the: /home/omar/ros_ws/baxter2.sh

Comment: it just prints if the server started correctly then updates the current status of the running server

Comment: When `/home/omar/ros_ws/baxter2.sh` is run from the terminal, does it return you to the bash prompt quickly (i.e. where you type commands, usually ending in `$ `) ?

Comment: @DanielMartin sorry I dont understand you question.